# JavaScript regex replace on hash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a replace on a hash so I can call a html file that matches its name.

For example:

`var url = '/partials/' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.html';`

and hash will be:

`#/home/`

at the moment it will only remove the `#`

what have I missed?

Comment: I think your code just replaces the # with nothing so it is removed

Comment: Give an example input and output. Get more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also want to remove the leading and trailing `/` as well. Try using a pattern like this:

```
/^#\/|\/$/g
```

For example:

```
var hash = '#/home/';
var url = '/partials/' + ( hash.replace( /^#\/|\/$/g, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.html';
console.log(url); // "/partials/home.html"
```

Or possibly try using `match` instead of `replace`, like this:

```
var hash = '#/home/';
var url = '/partials/' + ( hash.match(/\w[\w/]*\w/) || 'blank' ) + '.html';
console.log(url); // "/partials/home.html"
```